# Difference between souteneur and proxénète in late 19th-century French?

Tags: choix-de-mot, littérature

In the first chapters of Guy de Maupassant's novel *Bel-Ami*, the main character, Georges Duroy, is trying to learn the craft of journalism.
The end of the book's fourth chapter tells us that he meets all sorts of people while looking for news, information and gossip that may be used for articles (emphasis added):

> Il eut des rapport continus avec des ministres, des concierges, des généraux, des agents de police, des princes, des **souteneurs**, des courtisanes, des ambassadeurs, des évêques, des **proxénètes**, des rastaqouères, (...).

I have always assumed that [*souteneur*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/souteneur) and [*proxénète*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/proxenete) were synonyms. 
However, this would imply a repetition of the same concept in the above passange, which does not make much sense. Did late 19th-century French distinguish between two categories of pimps or does Maupassant have other meanings of "souteneur" and "proxénète" in mind? If the latter, which would be those meanings?

Comment: I won't dare to put it forward as the definite answer, but there is maybe a slight difference between the *souteneur* (who protects prostitutes in exchange for a share of their profits) and the *proxénète* (who merely organizes contacts with the clients, or owns a brothel). In many cases, both functions are then fullfilled by the same person. I have checked a couple of dictionaries, but I do not see this difference being clearly documented.

Comment: Upon seeing your literature.SE question, I looked at some 19th century French *dictionnaires d'argot* (which I found on Google books), and it seemed to me that a *souteneur* was a pimp (*un homme*), and a *proxénète* was  a madam (*une femme*). I'm too busy right now to do the research necessary to give a definitive answer, so if anybody else wants to, please go ahead.

Answer (score 5):

In the 19th century,  it appears that a souteneur was a pimp (un homme), and a proxénète was a madam (une femme).

If you look at this [Dictionnaire d'argot fin de siècle](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionnaire_d_argot_fin_de_si%C3%A8cle/3sJfSxB-XKsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=prox%C3%A9n%C3%A8te+c%27est+la+m%C3%AAme+chose&pg=PA232&printsec=frontcover) from 1894, on Google books, it says

> PROXÉNÈTE : ou maquerelle ; c'est la même chose.
>
> La proxénète est à l'affût de toutes les misères pour livrer les malheureuses à la prostitution.

Today, at least according to wiktionary, a [maquerelle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maquerelle) is a woman, a [souteneur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/souteneur) is a man, and [proxénète](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prox%C3%A9n%C3%A8te) has become a word that can apply to either sex.

Comment: Note that *maquerelle* has a matching masculine form: *maquereau*..

Answer (score 1):

The famous ***Littré*** dictionary (four volumes, 1880s) provides the following definition of [souteneur](https://archive.org/details/1889dictionnaire04littuoft/page/2020/mode/2up):

> **2** Particulièrement, celui qui se fait le champion d'une maison de jeu ou de quelque mauvais lieu. Un souteneur de filles.

Volume 3 of the same dictionary defines [proxénète](https://archive.org/details/1883dictionnaired03littuoft/page/1370/mode/2up) as follows:

> **2** Aujourd'hui, en mauvaise part, entremetteur de certains marchés honteux entre les deux sexes.

Delvau's ***Dictionnaire de la langue verte*** (literally "dictionary of green language", i.e. argot) defines [souteneur](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedela00delvuoft/page/424/mode/2up) as follows:

> Homme qui vit aux dépens des filles, — dans l'argot du peuple.

This dictionary has no entry for ["proxénète"](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedela00delvuoft/page/372/mode/2up),
although the term is used in entries for other terms (see [lanceuse](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedela00delvuoft/page/254/mode/2up) and
[ogresse](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedela00delvuoft/page/316/mode/2up), a "madam").

Delesalle's ***Dictionnaire Argot-Français & Français-Argot*** (1896) provides the following definition of [souteneur](https://archive.org/details/dictionnaireargo00deleuoft/page/274/mode/2up):

> Celui qui vit aux dépens des prostituées, et qu'on appelle ainsi parce qu'il est censé les soutenir quand elles sont instultées.

The dictionary entry for "proxénète" says "Voy. Entremetteur" (See "entremetteur"); the entry for "entremetteur" says "Voy. Proxénète. Voy. Rouspant, Dariolet, Dariolette, Eléphant".)

**Wiktionnaire** provides the following definition of [souteneur](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/souteneur):

> Celui qui, vivant du gain d’une prostituée, prétend assurer, en retour, sa protection.

The aspect of protection is mentioned by Littré but not by Delvau.

Wiktionnaire defines [proxénète](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prox%C3%A9n%C3%A8te) as follows:

> Personne qui tire profit de la prostitution d’autrui ou bien la favorise.

The definition does not state whether a *proxénète* is male or female, but quotes a sentence from Proust that illustrates that it could be a woman ("mais il l’aimait comme une proxénète").

Finally, Virmaitre's ***Dictionnaire d'argot fin-de-siècle*** (1894) provides the following definition of [proxénète](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedarg00virmuoft/page/232/mode/2up):

> Proxénète: Ou maquerelle; c'est la même chose.
>   La *proxénète* est à l'affût de toutes les misères pour livrer les malheureuses à la prostitution.

And [souteneur](https://archive.org/details/dictionnairedarg00virmuoft/page/276/mode/2up):

> Souteneur: Individu qui vit des filles qui se livrent à la prostitution, fainéant, voleur et assassin si l'occasion se présente; on le trouve en haut comme en bas de l'échelle sociale (Argot du peuple).

In summary, we have the following:

- A *proxénète* is a woman according to Virmaitre, and can be a woman based on Delvau and Wiktionnaire. Littré provides no information on this matter.
- A *souteneur* is a man (in fact, the ending *eur* already suggests this), who, according to Littré, Delesalle and Wiktionnaire, provides "protection" (the quotes are mine) while living of the gains made by prostitutes. The aspect of protection is not mentioned by Delvau and is at best ambiguous in Virmaitre.